# How do I pull a random key from a dictionary with a certain value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of words, each of which with a certain point value. I would dictionary to search though this dictionary for a random word with a specific point value, i.e. find a random word with a point value of 3. my dictionary is structured like this:

```py
wordList = {"to":1,"as":1,"be":1,"see":2,"bed":2,"owl":2,"era":2,"alive":3,"debt":3,"price":4,"stain":4} #shortened list obviously
```

Looked around online and I couldn't find a great answer, that or I did and I just didn't quite get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `if statement` and `random.choice` answers your problem in a short time

```
from random import choice

wordList = {"to": 1, "as": 1, "be": 1, "see": 2, "bed": 2, "owl": 2, "era": 2,
            "alive": 3, "debt": 3, "price": 4, "stain": 4}  # shortened list obviously
value = int(input())
lst = []
for key,val in wordList.items():
    if val == value:
        lst.append(key)

print(choice(lst))
```

one-liner:

```
choice([key for key, val in wordList.items() if val == value])
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `random.choice()` with a list comprehension:

```py
from random import choice

choice([word for word, count in wordList.items() if count == 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about performance, that will work but it will recreate a dictionary every time you access it:

```
random.choice([k for k,v in wordList.items() if v == 3])
```

otherwise it's could be better to create a reversed dictionary, to save the time in multiple runs:

```
from random import choice
from collections import defaultdict
rev = defaultdict(list)
for k, v wordList.items():
    rev[v].append(k)

...

choice(rev[3])
```